# Python: How to run module from the command line

Tags: python, program-entry-point

I have the following project structure:

[image]

and I would like to be able to run my project from the command line using something like:

```
hotel-reservation> python hotel_reservation
```

However, when doing this I am receiving the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'hotel_reservation'
```

The code that I have in `__main__.py` is something as:

```
from hotel_reservation.utils import get_client_type_and_dates
from hotel_reservation.hotel import Hotel
from hotel_reservation.hotel_reservation_system import HotelReservationSystem


def main():
    # CODE
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I guess I am missing how to indicate python that hotel_reservation is a the parent directory, so how can I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need an `__init__.py` to make a directory into a module

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/q/448271/416224 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/419163/416224.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I just have to create the __init__.py inside hotel_resevation or do I have to include something there?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: I have added `__init__.py` to `hotel-reservation`, `hotel_reservation`, and `tests`, but I am still getting the same error about not having that module.

Comment: I have also added `__all__ = ["hotel", "hotel_reservation_system", "utils"]` in the `__init__` file for hotel_reservation.